# how to create Request Performance Behavior for signalr

Tags: c#, signalr

Who knows. How can i do something like this for signal r hub?
Are there any hub tools for embedding into the request processing pipeline besides filters?

```
    public class RequestPerformanceBehaviour<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    {
        private readonly Stopwatch _timer;
        private readonly ILogger<TRequest> _logger;

        public RequestPerformanceBehaviour(ILogger<TRequest> logger)
        {
            _timer = new Stopwatch();

            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
        {
            _timer.Start();

            var response = await next();

            _timer.Stop();

            if (_timer.ElapsedMilliseconds > 500)
            {
                var name = typeof(TRequest).Name;
                _logger.LogWarning("Long Running Request: {Name}({ElapsedMilliseconds} milliseconds) {@Request}", name, _timer.ElapsedMilliseconds,request);
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable tracing and logging to track SignalR performance. Then you can also observe metrics following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-5.0#signalr-server-metrics).